# linq c# group by multiple columns using a string to specify what columns to use for duplicate checking

Tags: c#

Imagine I have a class

```
class Subject{
   string firstname;
   string lastname;
}
```

I have a list of subjects

```
 List<Subject> subjects;
```

I have a duplicatecheck string which is a comma delimetered list of columns to check the list for duplicates. i.e

```
firstname (only check subjects using the firstname column for duplicates)
firstname,lastname  (check both firstname and lastname columns for duplicates)
```

What's the easiest way to filter and sort the subjects list so that only the duplicates are in the list and they are sorted in the order of the duplicatecheck string

```
i.e firstname,lastname (duplicate subjects are sorted by firstname first)
i.e lastname,firstname (duplicate subjects are sorted by lastname first)
```

Comment: You can use reflection for that, but I would recommend just some simple bool flags, that saves a lot of overhead and memory.

Comment: You'll find sharing your code helpful. Here's how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).